# calling function from an array with time delay

Tags: swift

Let's say I have this array of functions:

```
lazy var funcArray = [firstFunc, secondFunc, thirdFunc, ....n+Func, ...Inifinit number of Func........]
```

How would you call them one after the other with a 2.5 second delay?

I have tried without success many things including this while loop:

```
while n < funcArray.count {
    funcArray[n]()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.5) {
        n = n +1
    }
}
```

Comment: i wonder if a recursive function using performSelector with afterDelay works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i write small code for better understanding.

initialize count and funcTimer variable and created static function array .

```
var count:Int = 0
var funcTimer = Timer()
let funcArray:Array = [somefunc(),somefunc(),somefunc()]
```

After that add these line in appropriate place

```
funcTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.5, target: self, selector: (#selector(ViewController.scheduleArrayFunctions)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func scheduleArrayFunctions(funcarray:[ String])
{
    if count < self.funcArray.count {

        //this if is interesting checking both static function when it check it call the somefunc method
        if self.funcArray[count] == ViewController.somefunc(){
            print("equel")
        }
        self.count += 1
    }
    else
    {
       funcTimer.invalidate()
    }

}

func somefunc()
{
    print("hello world")
}
```

Hope so this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. Follow these steps.

- Declare a variable count as zero.
- Schedule a timer with time interval 2.5 and repeat to true.
- Now call the function from the array with index as count inside the timer callback block.
- Check if the count is less than array.count.
- Increment the count.
- Otherwise stop the timer.

Comment: Don't forget to stop the timer when count gets too big.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work, but I'm noob so....instead I did a function to function loop

Answer (score 0):

I did a function to function loop 
probably bad coding but...it works

```
        n = 0            

       self.funcArray[n]()

        n = n + 1

        timerAction()

func timerAction() {



    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2.5
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
    self.funcArray[self.n]()


    self.n = self.n + 1

        if self.n < self.funcArray.count {

    self.timerAction2()

        }

    }

}

func timerAction2() {



    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2.5
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
        self.funcArray[self.n]()
    }

    if self.n < self.funcArray.count {

        self.timerAction()

    }



    }
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a complete answer to your question? Answers (even our own) need to explain. Don't just post code. If this isn't actually an answer, please delete this answer and update your question as needed.